# Get specific character values from a SKU Field

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a SQL Server 2008 R2 statement in a stored procedure that takes a 9-character SKU value as input, and has to grab certain character values in specific positions of that input field and concatenate them to a value.

I wrote the following but it doesn't seem to be working, though that could just be me. It seems to make sense on paper...

```
 IF NOT @SKU = '' BEGIN
 
    DECLARE @StringPos SMALLINT = 1, @StringLen SMALLINT, @ColNum SMALLINT, @ItemVal VARCHAR(10)

    SET @StringLen = LEN(@RecallSortMode)
    WHILE @StringPos <= @StringLen BEGIN
        SET @ColNum = SUBSTRING(@RecallSortMode, @StringPos, 1)
        SET @ItemVal += SUBSTRING(@SKU, @ColNum, 1)
        SET @StringPos = @StringPos + 1
    END
    PRINT 'Item Val: ' + @ItemVal
   END
```

So, if the columns I need are 1, 2 and 9 the value of `@RecallSortMode` would be `129` and if the value of `@SKU` is 9 characters long and is `987654321` I'm looking for the statement to return an `@ItemVal` of `981`.

Does this work or am I doing something wrong? It seems to compile OK but I get back nothing from it.

Thanks

Comment: Initialize `@ItemVal` with `''`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NULL value returned when concatenating a string in SQL while loop!](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/68097/5203)

Comment: Yes, the initialize worked!  thanks!